# Creating GUI in IOS without using storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode

Is there a way I could create gui for ios using like xml in android. Storyboard is so heavy and make my computer unresponsive. I can't find any decent tutorial for creating gui through coding it

Comment: see this link http://www.sixpacksumo.com/ios-lesson-3-uiviewcontroller-programmatically/

Answer (score 0):

Well storyboard is an XML file only. As you can see by right clicking on it and opening it as a source file. 
You can create a storyboard and open it as a source file and it will open as an XML file. But mind it, its not a single Scene, its the whole scene of your application as a single XML file.

So you can configure it like that.

Comment: you're right. it just xml. do they have a documentation for this (about the syntax)? also why all the scene was put in one file only?

Comment: its a horrible idea to edit this xml yourself, only for serious debugging

Comment: ^as Fonix pointed it out Yes its a horrible idea coz the whole scene is a single XML file. I just wrote it coz he wanted to know if the XML file structure exists in iOS, but the method is highly sensitive and not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

first try with **.XIB**. it gives you amazing features of **auto-layout** functionality.

or you can create any view with code. eg. if you are using **swift** you can create your view like this.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true

    /////creating navigation bar//////////

    var _customNavView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 64))
    _customNavView.backgroundColor = headerColor
    self.view.addSubview(_customNavView)


    var _lblMapTitle = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(_customNavView.center.x-75,self.view.frame.origin.y+30,150,30))
    _lblMapTitle.text = "SETTINGS"
    _lblMapTitle.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    _lblMapTitle.font = UIFont(name: "ErasITC-Demi", size: 18)

    _lblMapTitle.textAlignment = .Center
    _customNavView.addSubview(_lblMapTitle)






    _imgCoverPic.frame = CGRectMake(0, _customNavView.frame.origin.y+_customNavView.frame.height, self.view.frame.size.width,160)
    _imgCoverPic.contentMode =  .ScaleAspectFill
    _imgCoverPic.alpha = 0.5
    _imgCoverPic.clipsToBounds = true

    self.view.addSubview(_imgCoverPic)



    _imgPicturePic.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.width/2-50, _imgCoverPic.frame.origin.y+30, 110 ,110)
    _imgPicturePic.clipsToBounds = true

    _imgPicturePic.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    _imgPicturePic.layer.borderWidth = 3
    _imgPicturePic.layer.cornerRadius = _imgPicturePic.frame.width/2
    self.view.addSubview(_imgPicturePic)




    ////////creating table view///////////

    var heightForTab :CGFloat = AppDelegate.sharedInstance.heightForTabBar as! CGFloat


    //println(heightForTab)


    get_all_status_value_for_user()

    _tblSettings.frame = CGRectMake(0,_imgCoverPic.frame.origin.y+_imgCoverPic.frame.size.height+15, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-heightForTab-64)
    _tblSettings.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None
    _tblSettings.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    // _tblSettings.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    // _tblEvent.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

    self.view.addSubview(_tblSettings)


}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Mohit tomar answer states, i would suggest using just xibs instead, they are a bit more light weight to edit. But what I would personally do, because storyboards give more functionality than xibs, is to break up your storyboard into very small storyboards, no more than 3 viewcontrollers on one. Then in code, if you need to segue to a viewcontroller on another storyboard, you can just load the storyboard manually and then segue to a particular viewcontroller on it programatically.

Its even possible to make your own custom segue that will segue to a view controller on another storyboard without having to write much code

```
@interface StoryboardLinkSegue () {

    NSString *segueType;
}

@end

@implementation StoryboardLinkSegue

+ (UIViewController *)viewControllerNamed:(NSString *)identifier
{
NSArray *info = [identifier componentsSeparatedByString:@"@"];

NSString *storyboardName = info[1];
NSString *viewControllerName = info[0];

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName
                                                     bundle:nil];
UIViewController *scene = nil;

if (viewControllerName.length == 0 || [viewControllerName isEqualToString:@"default"]) {
    scene = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
}
else {
    scene = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:viewControllerName];
}

return scene;
}

- (id)initWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier
              source:(UIViewController *)source
         destination:(UIViewController *)destination
{

NSArray *info = [identifier componentsSeparatedByString:@"@"];

if(info.count > 2){
    segueType = [info[2] lowercaseString];
}
else {
    segueType = @"push";
}

return [super initWithIdentifier:identifier
                          source:source
                     destination:[StoryboardLinkSegue viewControllerNamed:identifier]];
}

- (void)perform
{
if([segueType isEqualToString:@"push"]){
    [[self.sourceViewController navigationController] pushViewController:self.destinationViewController animated:YES];
}
else if ([segueType isEqualToString:@"modal"]) {
    [self.sourceViewController presentViewController:self.destinationViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
}
```

now if you make a segue to an empty viewcontroller in your storyboard, just put the segue identifier as `<storyboardName>@<viewControllerName>` and to be technical you can use `<storyboardName>@<viewControllerName>@modal` or `<storyboardName>@<viewControllerName>@push` to make it a modal or push segue. This will make it segue from one storyboard to another without having to write any code (besides copy pasting the code ive given you)

example: mainStoryboard@loginViewController
will go to the viewcontroller named loginViewController that is in the mainStoryboard

you just need to give all your viewcontrollers names in your storyboards under the identity inspector -> Storyboard ID